# Debug/Develop Firebase remotely with vs-code or anything

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, debugging, google-cloud-functions

I heard about [Firebase Local Emulator Suite](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite) and this is really cool for developing and debugging.
Unfortunately, we can't use them for our real case and the reason next: we have dozens of integrations and making everything to work locally almost impossible or will take too much time. Currently we have to redeploy functions after every change (deploy takes us 5-6 minutes, because of related libraries)
I'm trying to find a different solution, here is what I have:

- One of the ways to debug node process allows connecting via ssh [Debug node process](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/debugging-getting-started/#enabling-remote-debugging-scenarios)
- In vs code we can connect to server and update files right there [VS Code Remote Development](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/remote-overview)

**And the main question how to apply all mentioned earlier to Firebase project?**
I'll appreciate any directions, examples, experiences, docs, or other ways to solve our problem.

Comment: Hi, have you seen the [Cloud Shell Editor](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/editor-overview) ?

Comment: Hi @Pit, yes, I have seen it, but now I understand that it may help. I just need to investigate more about this tool. Thank you.